# Variance of a linear combinations

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

[image]

I was given the problem above. I am confused on how to find the variance of the linear combinations.

`A` for example would have a mean of 22 correct? Can someone explain how I can use that info to find the variance for `A`?

Comment: Keep in mind that expected value is linear, and that the variance of $Z$ is just $E[Z^2]-(E[Z])^2$

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, or even just uncorrelated, the variance of $aX+bY$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants,  is $a^2\text{Var}(X)+b^2\text{Var}(Y)$.  Also, if $k$ is a constant, then $\text{Var}(W+k)=\text{Var}(W)$.

Comment: @AlexBecker so how does it change with a linear combination?

Comment: @Deekor Well, $E[aZ+bW]=aE[Z]+bE[W]$.

Comment: @AlexBecker so would it be (2(5) - 1^2) + (20 - 20^2)

Comment: @Deekor What is "it"?

Comment: @AlexBecker the variance for part `A`

Comment: @Deekor No. We have $$E[(2X+20)^2]=E[4X^2+40X+400]=4E[X^2]+40E[X]+400=460$$ and I'll let you do $(E[2X+20])^2$ yourself.

Comment: @AlexBecker oh so Z is the entire linear combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $E[2X+20]=2E[X]+20=22$.

For the variance, you want $$E[(2X+20)^2]-(E[2X+20])^2 = E[4X^2+40X+400]-22^2$$ $$=4E[X^2]+40E[X]+400-22^2 $$ and you know $E[X^2]$ and $E[X]$.

All the others are similar, though you should note that as $X$ and $Y$ are assumed to be independent you have $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$.